# How should you describe turning pages quickly?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, description, phrasing

I want to describe this action. How should I describe this action?

[image]

Comment: [Riffling](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riffle) through the book.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect your question will be closed as it *leans* to asking what to write (I'm not completely sure though, so no close vote from me *yet*), but I'll give you some of my ideas anyway.

The GIF shows the reader *not really* comprehending what the book is saying (unless they are incredibly fast at reading), rather they are jumping across pages, perhaps to find a specific section, or just out of boredom.

I would describe that action with these words:

a) flipping through pages
b) skimming through pages
c) browsing
d) surfing through the book
e) scanning the book
f) thumbing through pages

And then I would put them into sentences like:

> a) Juliet **carelessly flipped through the pages**. "Ugh," she groaned, "this was such a stupid assignment."

> b) **Skimming through the pages**, George finally found something of interest: Mart's address.

> c) Hank sighed. Another day, another book, it was getting old. He **quickly browsed through** the dusty collection of fairy tales before archiving it in the library's catalog.

> d) Maya **surfed through** her favorite book, she had read it hundreds of times, but it was the next best thing to do in her boredom.

> e) Jack **scanned** the manuscript for errors only to find that the book was free of mistakes. Disappointed, he forwarded the attachment to a different beta reader.

> f) **Thumbing through** her yearbook, Jessica had the intention of finding her face to see if her photo turned out right.

Comment: That is exactly what my character is doing too. Flipping pages just out of boredom, but I was looking for more of a one word

Comment: @Gurkirat Ok. I will edit in other options to my answer, but next time, know that it is expected to include all necessary information in your question (such as more than a one-word description).

Comment: Ok. I actually like the 'f' option, but if there is a word for it then I kind of prefer a word, it is cleaner. But still thanks

Comment: @Gurkirat Thanks, I just edited my post.

Comment: @Momobear Technically, *thumbed* would be one word.

Answer (score 2):

I would describe the action in the gif as ***riffling***.

> Riffle - *gerund or present participle: riffling*
>
> turn over something, especially the pages of a book, quickly and casually.
> "he riffled through the pages"

This implies a casual action, if you want a similar process but implied urgency then you could use the similarly spelled ***rifling***

> Rifle - *gerund or present participle: rifling*
>
> search through something in a hurried way in order to find or steal something.
> "she rifled through the pages"

Although I think rifling would be more appropriate for loose pages on a desk rather than in a book.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming.
Like taking cream off milk. Cream of the crop.

Breezing.
Very casually. Sort of annulling the very incentivizing purpose.

Flipping. *

And cycling. Cycled.
As if it was a hanging calendar or scoreboard that resets when over-used.

Comment: What does “...annulling the very incentivizing purpose.” mean? (Without from the spelling mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Well, what your animation shows is someone riffling pages as one other answer states.

But an alternative understanding relates to the older flip book technique (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_book) that animated *.gif files digitally reprise/simulate.

So, you have choices, 'flip' or 'riffle' through. I prefer 'riffle through' as it implies going rapidly; whereas, to me, 'flip through' implies a casual perusal maybe seeking/hunting through to a page you stopped off at some time ago and regretfully forgot to place a bookmark.